# How to give dotted effect to sides of a photograph?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

[image]

See image. 
Can this be done using photoshop, indesign or illustrator?

Using this opportunity to wish all a happy easter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Photoshop you can achieve this effect in a number of ways. One such way would be to create a layer filled with white with a black rectangle in the middle. Make this a smart object so you can change the properties to your desired effect. Add a Gaussian Blur and then Color Halftone (Filter > Pixellate > Color Halftone ...). Now make the layer's blending mode Screen:

[image]

This will give you an effect like this over whatever your background or layer below is:

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell step by step from opening new file? Not able to achieve it, seems erring one step :(

Comment: What effect did you get?

Comment: Not getting dotted effect :(
http://s3.postimg.org/ojxyq4msz/2bbb.jpg

Comment: Did you create a layer and fill it with white? After which you'd add a black rectangle and turn that layer or layers into a smart object.